# Different code when translation is added & another when save button is clicked

Tags: i18n-l10n

Is there a way for me to add a code when i first add a translation and a separate code when the save button is clicked. at the moment i am using form _alter to trigger my custom code when adding, My problem is that the same code runs when the save button is clicked. How do i prevent the save action from running this code? Any help will do. Thanks

```
case 'node_interactive_form':
 //To use to check if it is a default language -- returns 0 = false & 1 = true
 $is_original_language = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->get('default_langcode')->value;

 if( !$is_original_language && !$form_state->isSubmitted() ) {
    var_dump("only run when adding & not when saving");
    // $triggering_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    // $button_name = $triggering_element['#name'];

  }

break;
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) It's left unclear what you are trying to do exactly. Why would you need that functionality at all?

Comment: @leymannx I am using a module that is not fully supported for multilingual, so I have to create entries in the modules database table for each translation by copying the English version. I could obviously add this when they submit the form,  but they will not be able to edit the content beforehand as it will not exist. My solution was to perform the database insertion when the first add a translation so the data can be available to edit. Although Upon saving; the form_id ('node_interactive_form':) is run again, this overrides any addition. I fixed it by adding a new column to track changes.